# Cubic cyclic field families

Tags: polynomials, extension-field, cyclic-groups, cubics

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of rational numbers. If $f(t,x)=x^3+(t+2)x^2+(t-1)x-1$, **show that for any integer $t$**, adjoining a root $r$ of $f(t,x)$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ will yield a cyclic cubic field. Once this is shown, if possible, find a quintic (degree $5$) polynomial $f(t,x)$ (coefficients in terms of $t$) such that for any integer $t$, adjoining a root of $f(t,x)$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ will yield a cyclic quintic field. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you shown that $f(n,x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ for any integer $n$ in place of $t$?

Comment: Some discussion of the quintic case at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946527/cyclic-quintic-polynomial-family

Answer (score 1):

Note that if (for fixed $t$) $\alpha$ is a root of $f(t, x)$ then so is $-1-\alpha^{-1}$. The transformation $y \mapsto -1 -y^{-1}$ has order three. Maybe it is possible to find something similar for the quintic case.