# Cyclic Quintic Polynomial Family

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, cyclic-groups

Is there another known cyclic quintic family other than Lehmer's simplest quintic, which is well known? For instance, in this [pdf](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-251/S0025-5718-05-01750-3/S0025-5718-05-01750-3.pdf), in section (4.2) when the parameters $(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4)$ are set to $s_1=n+1, s_2=n+2, s_3=1, s_4=n+3$, Lehmer's simplest quintic is obtained. What is the two parameter polynomial when $s_1=n-1, s_2=-1, s_3=-1, s_4=n$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996552/any-more-cyclic-quintics  That is a nice article. Gauss periods are done in modern terms in Galois Theory by Cox.

Comment: many, many examples in https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Answer (score 3):

Such families are easily construct able now.

In [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-136/S0025-5718-1976-0412089-9/S0025-5718-1976-0412089-9.pdf) paper, specializing the parameters $v = 2n+1, w = 1, u = 0$ leads to

$p = n^4 + 2n^3 + 14n^2 + 13n + 11$

Certain linear transformations of the Gaussian Quintic of conductor $p$ lead to the family

$x^5 + (n^2 + n + 4)x^4 + (-2n^2 - 2n + 2)x^3 + (-n^4 - 2n^3 - 10n^2 - 9n - 5)x^2 + (-3n^2 - 3n - 2)x + n^2 + n + 1$

The discriminant of this polynomial is

$(2n + 1)^4(n^2 + n + 1)^2p^4$